# java.io.file backslash saving in weblogic's root

Tags: java, file, weblogic, java-io, fileoutputstream

I have a java application running into a weblogic server.

The application have to write a file into the path `\bla\john doe` *(for example)*.

For this, I used the `java.io.File` library to:

```
1. Verify if the path exists
2. If not, create it.
3. Verify if the file exists
4. if not, create it
5. Write the bytes into the file.
```

The correct behavior would be to create the directory `bla` into the root of the weblogic's current domain and then create a `john doe` inside it.

**The problem is:** in my current enviroment it works like a charm, but in the client's one, the application does not consider the **backslash** as an element of the path, and instead of creating two directories, the application only creates one, literally named as `\bla\john does`.

So, instead of:

```
-domain_root
    -bla
        -john does
```

I get the following:

```
-domain_root
    -\bla\john does
```

*(and if I escape it, occurres the same but with two backslash)*

The odd is that if I use the commom slash (`/bla/john doe`), it works..

```
-domain_root
    -bla
        -john does
```

Does any one knows what possibly can be happening?

---

script for check the path

```
public File checkPath(String path) {
    File f = new File(cls_Util.NeutralizeFilePath(path));
    if (!(f.exists() && f.isDirectory())) {
        try {
            f.mkdirs();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

script for check the file:

```
public File checkFile(String path){
    File f = new File(path);
    return checkFile(f);
}

public File checkFile(File f) {
    if (!(f.exists() && f.isFile())) {
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

script for create file

```
public File writeFile(String path, byte[] binaryfile) {
    File file = checkFile(path);

    if (file != null) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
            try {
                fos.write(binaryfile);
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And to create the file:

```
String filePathPub = pathPub + newName;
File FilePathPub = writeFile(filePathPub, p_Arquivo);
```

Comment: Just use /. It works in all environments. NB Your steps 3 and 4 are redundant. new FileOutputStream() already does that. Don't reinvent the wheel. Save yourself 16 lines of code too. NB File.mkdirs() does not throw exceptions except maybe NPE.

Comment: Ok, but the core purpose for this is to access (and write a file) into a network path, e.g. `\\server\directory`, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: You could still try it. Post some code. Is the client running Windows?

Comment: The O.S. running in the client is the `soselinux`... *(I will give a try in your suggestion)*

Comment: So if the client isn't running Windows why are you providing a filename with backslashes? *Of course* it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows the `\` starts an absolute path; on Unix/Linux the backslash is a valid filename character (and therefore starts a relative path).

I would suggest you try to avoid using file name concatenation platform specific separators if you are not familiar with the semantic:

```
File current = new File();
File bla = new File(current, "bla");
```

(or simply stick to `/` (forward slash as used by Unix) to separate path components). Java translates this to the Windows character automatically).